# Compute hash function in range 0..n

Tags: algorithm, hash

I have an array of strings. Array has length n. How to compute hash key for each string, so each key will be a number in range of 0..n?

UPDATE

Array's items could be not strings, but numbers if it will helps to someone to help me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot choose a hash function for this without first looking at contents of the array. Suppose you pick a hash function and let me pick the array. I generate 2n strings, apply the hash function, and sort the result. With 2n strings and only n possible values there must be collisions, so I pick n strings that include lots of collisions and give them back to you to hash and observe the collisions.

If you are prepared to do the work of analysing the strings ahead of time to choose your hash function one starting point - or source of search terms - would be "Minimal perfect hash function" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function.

You could also consider whether this is really what you want, and whether you could consider using a less perfect hash function. I like the look of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing, myself.

Answer (score 3):

Try modulo N:

```
int N = array.Length;
int hashMaxN = strings[i].GetHashCode() % N;
```

This will not guarantee unique hashes for different indices. But a hash code isn't unique.

If you want a unique id assigned to each string in a list, then use the suggestion from anothe r answer: pick the strings index in the sorted array of distinct strings

```
int itemHash = myList.Distinct().OrderBy(s => s).IndexOf(item);
```

This will have the property of being the same for the same string regardless of how the list is ordered *but* adding a string to the list will change the hash codes for the items.

Comment: I need an algorithm of building the hash. But even your approach with modulo doesn't work - as for example 31 % 3 = 1 and 13 % 3 = 1, so it doesn't guarantee uniqueness of the resulted hash

Comment: Edited my answer. Typically a hash code doesn't have the requirement to be unique (although one often tries to have as few collisions as possible for performance in hash tables).

Answer (score 1):

Late in the game, but this topic recently came up again with a [nicer solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13414764/1338292) than what I've seen here so far.

Take the CRC32 hash and use modulo to get a number within the desired range, e.g.:

```
crc32(str) % 5 // returns either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the index in the array as a hash key?

Comment: What if I have two equal strings in different positions? Their hash will be different while strings are equal.

Comment: He may wish to avoid `O(log(N))` probes into the list.  A hashing function is constant w.r.t `N` (just not key length.)

Comment: You need the list, if you want to be unique, *and* have the hashing function produce a number in 0..n :) It's basically the same as sorting, unless you want obfuscation.