# Simple hashing function to map variable length URLs to numbers (0...3)

Tags: php, algorithm, hash

My website use various resources from a single domain, for example:

```
http://static.example.com/javascript/common.js
http://static.example.com/javascript/common.css
http://static.example.com/javascript/menu/menu.js
http://static.example.com/javascript/menu/menu.css
http://static.example.com/images/1804/logo/02000100.jpg
http://static.example.com/images/1804/headers/main/09400060.png
http://static.example.com/images/1804/headers/home/1101/06900200-01.jpg
http://static.example.com/images/1804/headers/home/1101/06900200-02.jpg
```

I need a very simple string hashing function that maps these URLs to numbers, the numbers being 0, 1, 2 and 3. The algorithm should be deterministic and uniform. I have tagged the question PHP but a generic answer is acceptable.

You might have guessed why I need this; I plan to change the URLs to, for example:

```
http://0.static.example.com/javascript/common.js
http://2.static.example.com/javascript/common.css
```

Comment: I was going to say `strlen($str) % $num` ... it's definitely fast :)

Comment: Yes fast but not uniform... see the urls containing the word _headers_? I'll have about 15 of them on a page so 15 out of 20 URLs will have hash = 3.

Comment: Yeah that would admittedly be more applicable to the more human like image names :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer doing a `crc32` hash of the string, and taking its modulo with the limit.

Code:

```
function numeric_hash($str, $range) {
    return sprintf("%u", crc32($str)) % $range;
}
```

Usage:

```
$str = "http://static.example.com/javascript/common.js
http://static.example.com/javascript/common.css
http://static.example.com/javascript/menu/menu.js
http://static.example.com/javascript/menu/menu.css
http://static.example.com/images/1804/logo/02000100.jpg
http://static.example.com/images/1804/headers/main/09400060.png
http://static.example.com/images/1804/headers/home/1101/06900200-01.jpg
http://static.example.com/images/1804/headers/home/1101/06900200-02.jpg";
$urls = explode("\n", $str);

foreach($urls as $url) {
    echo numeric_hash($url, 4) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
3
3
1
3
1
3
```

Comment: What's with `hexdec`? I get negative numbers with your example code which is not a problem by the way.

Comment: @SalmanA, oops, I thought `crc32` returns a hex val. You must be on 32 bit php  where the function can return negative integers according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php). I'm sure wrapping it up in `abs()` will also give you a normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of URLs you should just a strong hashing and then take `mod <noBuckets>`

```
MD5(URL) % 4
```

If you have few URLs or you have uneven size or call frequency a "random" distribution might be bad and you should just create four lists and statically assign your URLs to each list, either manually or using some heuristic based on number of requests per URL.